# Using ASP.NET Repeaters with Object Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, nested-repeater

I'm trying to use ASP.NET's Repeater objects to loop over properties of an object.

For example... I have an ObjectDataSource to grab object "Program" by ID...

Program has properties such as Program.Stakeholders and Program.Outcomes which are Lists of "Stakeholder" and "Outcome" objects.

Now... what I'd really like to do is use the Repeaters to target these Properties and loop over the lists they contain. However, as far as I know I'd have to set up a separate data source for each one, tied to an individual method to retrieve each list.

Can anyone provide a better way to use these Repeater objects, or point me at some resources which would help? If this doesn't make sense I can try to clarify it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in `ObjectDataSource` mapping up a separate datasource for each item is probably the only straightforward way (and the only way that's easy enough to be worth the effort...).

Is it a requirement that you use the `ObjectDataSource`, or can you choose a different way to get the data from the storage? I would recommend either using Entity Framework (which imho rocks) or creating your own custom types to which you get the data with a custom designed DAL (which is a lot more work than using EF, but if you're, like some, concerned that EF is still in infancy this might be your option).

In either case, you'll end up with a C# class called `Program`, which has properties of type `IEnumerable<Stakeholder>` and `IEnumerable<Outcome>` called `Stakeholders` and `Outcomes` respectively. You can then use these as datasources for the item repeaters and set them in the `ItemDataBound` event of the `ProgramRepeater`, maybe something like this:

```
protected void ProgramRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, ItemDataBoundEvent e) {
    Program dataItem = (Program)e.DataItem;
    Repeater stakeholderRptr = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("ProgramRepeater");
    Repeater outecomeRptr = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("OutcomeRepeater");

    stakeholderRptr.DataSource = dataItem.Stakeholders;
    stakeholderRptr.DataBind();
    outecomeRptr.DataSource = dataItem.Outcomes;
    outecomeRptr.DataBind();
}
```

This is assuming that you're using ASP.Net WebForms, of course. In ASP.Net MVC it is even easier - you just send the `Program` object to the `View` as the `Model` object, and loop through its `Stakeholders` and `Outcomes` in a couple of nested `for` loops directly on the `View`.

---

**Note:** All code is provided as is, and I do not guarantee that it will run as expected or even compile. It is just to give you an idea of what to make your code do - not necessarily the exact code you need to solve your problem.

Comment: I'll admit that a lot of this is over my head. We already have some level of DAL established, but I'm not sure how it fits in here. What's the real benefit of doing it this way rather than just foreach looping over my code and writing custom methods for templates? That option seems easier and is awfully tempting.

I'm looking into the IEnumerable to get more direct control over the Repeaters, but I haven't worked with it before. I think it'll take me a bit to figure out exactly what's up. The exception the Repeater threw suggested IListSource as well.